# Extending custom dijit "chained constructor" error

Tags: inheritance, dojo

I have an issue when trying to extend a widget, giving me the error:

> declare ImageBoxAnim: calling chained constructor with inherited

I was unsuccessful in finding anyone with the same issue, so I assume it's my lack of understanding when it comes to `dojo/_base/declare`.

Base Class "_ImageBoxBase" (grotesquely simplified):

```
define(['dojo/_base/declare', 'dijit/_WidgetBase'], function(declare, _WidgetBase){
    return declare('_ImageBoxBase', [_WidgetBase], {
        constructor : function(){...}
    }
})
```

ImageBox (subclass 1 of _ImageBoxBase):

```
define(['dojo/_base/declare', './_ImageBoxBase'], function(declare, _ImageBoxBase){
    return declare("ImageBox", [_ImageBoxBase], {
        constructor : function(){
            this.inherited(arguments)
            // this class works like a charm
        }
    }
})
```

ImageBoxAnim (subclass of ImageBox):

```
define(['dojo/_base/declare', './ImageBox'], function(declare, ImageBox){
    return declare("ImageBoxAnim", [ImageBox], {
        constructor : function(){
            this.inherited(arguments)
            // no worky!
        }
    }
})
```

I've tried a lot of variations with the declare statement, and the only thing that will at least allow the script to not throw an error is a null "parent" class, but at that it doesn't widgitify.  It'll render the HTML/CSS as it sits, but NO methods are called in the returned `declare` object.

Essentially there's functionality in the `ImageBox` class I'd like `ImageBoxAnim` to inherit, while adding more functionality (animations).

The thing that gets me is when defining the ImageBox class, it's the same syntax and, I thought, the same process to extend `_WidgetBase` as it is to extend something that extends `_WidgetBase`.  A lot of online examples give ways to extend built-in dijits, so I don't see where I'm going wrong.

Note: I know these aren't technically "classes", but from an extending/sub/superclass point of view, it's easier to verbalize.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't be sure, but I imagine you're seeing problems because constructors are automatically chained (no need to call this.inherited). If you want to chain manually, check out [manual constructor chaining](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/_base/declare.html#manual-constructor-chaining)

Comment: That's what I had thought as well. However, even when taking out the inherited call and, even further, taking out all constructor, postCreate, etc calls it still throws. I'll try to put a fiddle or test page together tonite and post.

Comment: I'm not sure what I had done, probably something silly, but my other dijits are operating as expected.  I'll revisit.